# Entity Framework GroupJoin and Include

Tags: entity-framework

For some reason I wasn't able to include any of the object related entities in a GroupJoin statement.

```
public class Faclility{public List<Room> {get;set;}}
public class Room{public List<Chairs> {get;set;}}

dbContext.Facilities.GroupJoin(db.Room.Include(x=>x.Chairs),f=>f.fUnit‌​ID,r=>r.fUnitID,(f,result)=> new {})
```

The query works, i got some results back. However all "Chair" objects are null.

Answer (score 0):

Don't Chairs need to be

```
public virtual List<Chairs> {get;set;}
```

Also, how are you mapping chairs to room? Using Fluent API?